# JSON list of users not binding to model in Web API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I have a JSON object coming into a controller in Web API that isn't binding to my model. I'm testing it using Fiddler, with the following JSON in the body:

```
{
"userList": {
    "user": [
        {
            "custCode": "test1",
            "userName": "TheDude",
            "admin": "false",
            "effectiveDate": "2/14/2014"
        },
        {
            "custCode": "test1",
            "userName": "Bob",
            "admin": "false",
            "effectiveDate": "2/14/2014"
        },
        {
            "custCode": "test1",
            "userName": "Ted",
            "admin": "false",
            "effectiveDate": "2/14/2014"
        },
        {
            "custCode": "test1",
            "userName": "Darryl",
            "admin": "false",
            "effectiveDate": "2/14/2014"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I've included the classes built for the model and the controller method as well.

```
public class UserList
{
    public List<User> userList { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string custCode { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public bool admin { get; set; }
    public DateTime effectiveDate { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
    public void CreateNewUser(UserList newUsers)
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        try
        {
            foreach (var user in newUsers.userList)
            {
                //SQL code is here
            }
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Its hanging up on the foreach loop, giving me an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. I'm noticing that when it first hits the method, the UserList object is null. I'd appreciate any observations on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: shouldn't your root object should be newUsers to match the parameter coming into the method?

Comment: The other issue you're going to have is the date isn't going to deserialize properly in JSON.NET  You either need to make you effectiveDate a string and then convert it before before sending it to sql or change the incoming json to the right date format.

Comment: BlackICE - even if I add an extra wrapper with newUsers on the JSON object, its still coming in null. I've tried every variation I could think of.

Comment: cgotberg - The date was saving into the database fine as is when I was sending a single user JSON object, so I assume it will work this time.

Comment: You are setting a proper Content-Type header on your request, right?

Comment: Yes, I've made sure that is set properly on Fiddler. I learned that correction the hard way a few months ago. haha

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by doing the following:

I changed the UserList class to a string array:

```
public class UserList
{
    public User[] users { get; set; }
}
```

Then I re-formatted my request body JSON:

```
 {
    "users": [
        {
            "custCode": "test1",
            "userName": "TheDude",
            "admin": "false",
            "effectiveDate": "2/14/2014"
        },
        {
            "custCode": "test1",
            "userName": "Bob",
            "admin": "false",
            "effectiveDate": "2/14/2014"
        },
        {
            "custCode": "test1",
            "userName": "Ted",
            "admin": "false",
            "effectiveDate": "2/14/2014"
        },
        {
            "custCode": "test1",
            "userName": "Darryl",
            "admin": "false",
            "effectiveDate": "2/14/2014"
        }
    ]
}
```

After the changes, I re-tested using Fiddler and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

It should be this way:

`public class OuterClass` having one `private UserList userList` and then one more class called:

`public class UserList` having one `private List<User> user`

Basically:

```
public class OuterClass
{
    private UserList userList {get; set; }
}

public class UserList
{
    private List<User> user {get; set; }
}
```

If you think some key names in JSON are incorrectly named, even I think so.